# Why the gradient of $C_L$-$\alpha$ graph increases with the Mach number?

Tags: aerodynamics, lift, airfoil

From the JAA ATPL Book 13 (Principles of flight) the gradient $\frac{dC_L}{d\alpha}$ of the $C_L$-$\alpha$ graph increases for higher Mach numbers. Can someone explain why this is the case?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This increase in lift curve slope with Mach is commonly predicted via the Prandtl-Glauert correction for 2D airfoil:

$$C_{l_\alpha}=\frac{C_{l_{\alpha_0}}}{\sqrt{1-M_\infty^2}}$$

where $C_{l_\alpha}$ is the 2D lift-curve slope, $C_{l_{\alpha_0}}$ is the 2D lift-curve slope in incompressible flow, and $M_\infty$ is the free-stream Mach number (Ref. *Anderson*, Fundamentals of Aerodynamics), and is accurate before local shock appears.

The physical reason is the magnification of pressure change due to density change (compressibility), as understood from the isentropic relation:

$$\frac{\rho}{\rho_\infty}=\left(\frac{p}{p_\infty}\right)^{1/\gamma}$$

where $\rho$ is density and $p$ is pressure (Ref. *Drela*, Flight Vehicle Aerodynamics).